# How to split a string based on a combination of characters?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string (path) that looks like this:

```
list_string = ["\path\to\file1.json\path\to\file2.json\path\to\file3.json"]
```

How can I split this string into the correct list of paths ?

Current code:

```
for line in list_string:
     line.split('\p')
```

Desired output:

```
list_string = ["\path\to\file1.json", "\path\to\file2.json", "\path\to\file3.json"]
```

Comment: do all the files have a json extension?

Comment: NuLo, yes they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're all `json` files, you can simply do:

```
list_string = ["\\path\\to\\file1.json\\path\\to\\file2.json\\path\\to\\file3.json"]
files = [l.replace(".json",".json ").split() for l in list_string]
```

Comment: did you see your out: i got : `[['\\path',
  'o',
  'ile1.json',
  '\\path',
  'o',
  'ile2.json',
  '\\path',
  'o',
  'ile3.json']]`

Comment: i don't change any thing

Comment: @user1740577 - You should change "\" to "\\" (i.e. escape the "\"). See the below answer. For example, if the string had "\name". Your editor would think this was [newline]ame if you don't do "\\name"

Answer (score 3):

```
list_string = ["\\path\\to\\file1.json\\path\\to\\file2.json\\path\\to\\file3.json"]
>>> print(list_string[0])
\path\to\file1.json\path\to\file2.json\path\to\file3.json

import re
result = re.findall(r"\\.*?\.json", list_string[0])
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
\path\to\file1.json
\path\to\file2.json
\path\to\file3.json
```